# EC2 Reserved Instance - Are 24 instances running 1 hour (in the same hour) equal to 1 instance running 24 hours?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, billing

I understand that reserved instances in AWS are more of a billing thing rather actual instances - they're not attached to an actual instance - and I wonder:

If I buy a reserved instance of a specific time in a specific region and availability zone - will I be billed the same rate if I use a single instance 24 hours a day vs. running 24 instances (same size, same availability zone) for 1 hour (same hour, e.g. 00:00-01:00) every day?

Is there a difference in the types of reserved instances with regards to this question?

If the answer is no, and obviously the case is not such a clear cut (i.e. I have instances coming and going all the time - some work simultaneously and some on different times) - how can I make the calculation whether or not it makes sense for me to purchase reserved instances?

Comment: I have a hunch that this is the case. Let me do some digging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### <strike>I believe</strike> not.

It is not obvious from their product description, but it stands to reason, that "reserving an instance" and "long term commitment" should not be abused to have 365 instances running 1 day be as cost-effective as having the intended 1 instance for a whole year.

Using this logic you would also ask - why should I reserve more than one instance? I'll just bill all my instances on a single instance commitment - hardly a commitment, right?

Anyway, on my billing (where I have some reserved instances) I see:

> USD 0.1905126763 per Linux/UNIX, m1.large instance-hour (or partial
>   hour) (blended price)*

I believe that `blended price` mean that I have more instances than I reserved, so the hourly fee is a blend between the regular hourly fee ($0.24) and the reserved instance fee ($0.084)

**Update**

From AWS's documentation on [Blended rates](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/about/AboutConsolidatedBilling.html) (thanks @user3319714):

> Linked Account 1 has purchased three Reserved Instances and has used
>   2,100 hours of the reservation. Due to fluctuations in application
>   load, 60 reserved instance hours remain, which can be applied to other
>   eligible usage in the account family. In addition, application load
>   **when all three reserved instances were already running** has
>   necessitated an additional 40 hours of on-demand usage.

From this it is obvious that running more instances that you've actually reserved will not be billed are reserved.

Comment: blended fee is actually a term AWS uses in consolidated billing only - see here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/about/AboutConsolidatedBilling.html

Answer (score 1):

**Certainly Not**

Reserved instances are a mean to provision the required infrastructure to handle the demand, and are cost effective in the long term.

In the presented scenario you would be billed for processing time of 1 reserved instance and 23 onDemand instances.

You may try to find a balance between using reserved instances, onDemand instances and spot instances.

For detailed information take a look at the following [documentation](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/purchasing-options/).

Comment: Hi, Their docs are not too specific wrt my question - and I'm positive that if I run a few instances **not concurrently** (of the same type in the same AZ) and I purchased a reserved instance, then I'll be charged the reserved instance price. I understand that reserved instances are about demand, but it's still a billing mechanism and it seems like a hard task to track concurrent usage and bill that. Do you have any proof?

Comment: if all your instances are from the same type, and they are down, you will be charged by the EBS storage and elastic IP if you use. When you bring up the first instance you will be charged for the reserved instance time, if you bring another one you will be charged for the on demand instance time.